# ggplot legend size when using using breaks

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend-properties

if I use ggplot on this dataframe

```
library(ggplot2)

date <- as.Date(c("2019-12-18",
                  "2019-12-19",
                  "2019-12-20",
                  "2019-12-23",
                  "2019-12-24",
                  "2019-12-26",
                  "2019-12-27",
                  "2019-12-30"))


measures <- c( 0.0000000000,
                0.0012376239,
                -0.0024768434,
                0.0024768434,
                0.0043196611,
                0.0091939970,
                -0.0006103144,
                -0.0030571104)
                
theData <- data.frame(date, measures, I=measures<0)


ggplot(theData) +  geom_point( aes(x=date, y=measures, col=as.factor(I), size=factor(I))) +
                                scale_size_discrete(range = c(0.8, 2), guide="none") +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("grey80", "steelblue4"), breaks = c("TRUE"), labels = c("negative")) + 
  labs( col="") +
  theme(legend.position = c(0.2, 0.8))
# )
```

the legend box keeps the space for the FALSE level in the variable I. I tried resizing the legend box with `legend.margin`,  but with no success. If the background of the legend and of the plot are different, it looks quite ugly. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the empty gap on the top of the legend was not a space left for the unused factor level "FALSE", but an empty line due to `labs( col="")`.
The correct way to eliminate the legend title is `legend.title = element_blank()`. Further fine tuning for the label margins can be obtained through `legend.margin`.
My complete ggplot command is:

```
ggplot(theData) +  geom_point( aes(x=date, y=measures, col=as.factor(I), size=factor(I))) +
scale_size_discrete(range = c(0.8, 2), guide="none") +
scale_color_manual(values = c("grey80", "steelblue4"), breaks = c("TRUE"), labels = c("negative")) + 
theme(legend.position = c(0.2, 0.8), legend.title = element_blank(), legend.margin = margin(0, 0.3, 0.2, 0.2, "cm"))
```